# How to merge multiple object arrays into one array cross with sub array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have two arrays of objects:

```
 1) 
   [
    {
     "userId": 9
    },
    {
      "userId": 14
     }
    ]

 2) 
   [{"role": "1", "group": "3"}, {"role": "1", "group": "2"}]
```

I would like to merge two arrays as follows:

```
[
 {"userId":9,"role":"1","group":"2"},
 {"userId":14,"role":"1","group":"2"}
 {"userId":9,"role":"1","group":"3"},
 {"userId":14,"role":"1","group":"3"}
]
```

I tried to use `let` however I couldn't find the way to manipulate switch the subarray :

```
let arr1 = [{"userId": 9}, {"userId": 14}];
let arr2 = [{"role": "1", "group": "3"}, {"role": "1", "group": "2"}];

let result = arr1.map(o => Object.assign(o, ...arr2));

console.log(result);
return result;
```

The result I got with the previous implementation is like this :

```
[{"userId":9,"role":"1","group":"2"},{"userId":14,"role":"1","group":"2"}]
```

However, I would like to get the result as follows :

```
[
 {"userId":9,"role":"1","group":"2"},
 {"userId":14,"role":"1","group":"2"}
 {"userId":9,"role":"1","group":"3"},
 {"userId":14,"role":"1","group":"3"}
]
```

Comment: Do you have JSON or do you have JavaScript objects? If it is not JSON (read the `json` tag description) then could you please remove the tag and word from your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over the two arrays like this and push the merged values into `result`:

```
arr1.forEach(e => {
  arr2.forEach(e2 => {
    result.push(Object.assign({}, e, e2));
  });
});
```

Which could also be written in ONE LINE:

`arr1.forEach(e => arr2.forEach(e2 => result.push(Object.assign({}, e, e2))));`

```js
const arr1 = [{
    "userId": 9
  },
  {
    "userId": 14
  }
];

const arr2 = [{
  "role": "1",
  "group": "3"
}, {
  "role": "1",
  "group": "2"
}];

const result = [];

arr1.forEach(e => {
  arr2.forEach(e2 => {
    result.push(Object.assign({}, e, e2));
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var a = [{
    "userId": 9
  },
  {
    "userId": 14
  }
]

var b = [{
  "role": "1",
  "group": "3"
}, {
  "role": "1",
  "group": "2"
}]

console.log(
  b.map(z=>a.map(x=>({...x, ...z}))).flat()
)
```

Comment: This is nice. It's too bad `flat()` isn't supported in Node or Edge yet.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using for loop

```
let arr1 = [{ "userId": 9 }, { "userId": 14 }]
let arr2 = [{"role": "1","group": "3"}, {"role": "1","group": "2" }] 
let result = [];
for (let group of arr2) {
  for (let user of arr1) [
    result.push(Object.assign({}, group, user))
  ]
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
//output is: 
// [
//  {"role":"1","group":"3","userId":9},
//  {"role":"1","group":"3","userId":14},
//  {"role":"1","group":"2","userId":9},
//  {"role":"1","group":"2","userId":14}
// ]
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wxdogh)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of looping through two arrays

```js
 var x = [
    {
     "userId": 9
    },
    {
      "userId": 14
     }
    ]

 var y = [{"role": "1", "group": "3"}, {"role": "1", "group": "2"}] 
 let result = []
 
y.forEach((v, i) =>{
  x.forEach((y,i) => result.push({...v, ...y}))
})

console.log(result);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pxvzOG?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking for a Cartesian product of the two arrays. `flatMap` is a useful function here. For each element of one array, merge it with all objects from the other array, then return a flat result.

```js
const a = [{userId: 9}, {userId: 14}];
const b = [{role: "1", group: "3"}, {role: "1", group: "2"}];

const merged = b.flatMap(ae => a.map(be => ({...be, ...ae})));
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix a `reduce` and `map` to boil it down to a single array of objects.

```js
let data = [{
    "userId": 9
  },
  {
    "userId": 14
  }
]

let metaData = [{
  "role": "1",
  "group": "3"
}, {
  "role": "1",
  "group": "2"
}];

let dataReducer = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 let metadataReducer = metaData.map((val) => {
      return {
           ...curr,
              ...val
           };
         }, []);
  
  return [...acc, ...metadataReducer];
}, []);

console.log(dataReducer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a short approach for an arbitrary count of arrays of objects.

```js
var array1 = [{ userId: 9 }, { userId: 14 }],
    array2 = [{ role: "1", group: "3" }, { role: "1", group: "2" }],
    result = [array1, array2]
        .reduce((a, b) =>
            a.reduce((r, v) =>
                r.concat(b.map(w => Object.assign({}, v, w))), []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```